# affordable library for analyzing texts/sentenses gramatically

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, nlp, grammar

I have project, to create application, that should do following:

- Application should take word or sentence as an input.
- It should analyse the word/sentence grammatically and should give grammatical information about it and its content.
- Based on this information my program should be able to recreate relations between members of the sentence.
- Program should also have editor, which will allow to write down "rules". This rules will be applied to the relations schema of the sentence to "answer simple questions".

For example: If input of my application is: "Tom has a green apple". And the question is of type: "What color is Tom's apple?", the program should give as an output "green".

I am looking for an affordable library **preferably javascript** library that will give grammatical information about words/sentences.

As my goal is to analyse only simple sentences and limited number of words, the library should also allow scalability for the future development and refinement of my program.

Which library would you recommend? I tried to search on the internet, but still no shure what to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a course project about NLP tools recently. To analyze text is easy though to provide answers is quite more difficult and you might need to look into that on your own. NLP is still pretty much a fledgling field.

Anyways for NLP tools the two most reliable options right now are [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) and [spaCy](https://spacy.io/). Both are open source and of really good quality, offering a wide variety of functionalities. There are other tools such as NLTK and Apache OpenNLP, but they are quite older, not so well maintained and much less usable.